# XML file to XBRL file

Tags: xml, xslt, taxonomy, xbrl

I would like to convert **xml** output file to **xbrl** file. Can I do it with **XSLT**  language if I know the taxonomy?

Comment: You can use XSLT to transform an XML input to **any** XML, HTML or plain-text format.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. It won't necessarily be easy, but it's certainly possible, and it's probably easier in XSLT than any other way (at least, once you know XSLT).

Comment: Tk you wery much for your answer!!

Comment: I agree with Mike's analysis, and would add a word of caution: there are more constraints on an XBRL instance than being a well-formed XML document, and being valid against the family of XBRL schemas. Using XSLT rather than coding on top of an XBRL processor requires a deep knowledge of the XBRL specifications as it puts the responsibility of XBRL compliance on your shoulders. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the taxonomy already then what you need is just the data which can either be fed from any data source including xml and can be used to generate the XBRL. 
You can then use xslt or can loop through data and add the data points in the xbrl document which confirms to xml.

If the template is very small I would use just the annotated template provided by the regulator and extract the data points info like the metrics, domain, dimensions and their owner. This you can get from their taxonomy as well which can either be an database or xsd file.

Comment: XBRL is fully valid XML, syntax-wise.